# mysql query doesn't work when from the php page when are in other language (hebrew)

Tags: php, mysql

My code is

```
<$php
$database = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "root", "picture");
$new_album = "CREATE TABLE `נסיון` ("
    . "id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
    . "pic VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,"
    . "des VARCHAR (40) )";
$database->query($new_album);
?>
```

but if i copy the query as

```
CREATE TABLE `ש` (
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
pic VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,des VARCHAR (40)
)
```

strait into the phpMyAdmin query segmant, it creates the table with the hebrew currect.

in the head tag, there is a `<meta charset="windows-1255"/>` which is working when i print or echo anything in hebrew.is there anything else i could change in the page settings to fix this?

Comment: having an html charset header is utterly meaning less. your html has absolutely NOTHING to do with the php->mysql connection.

Comment: so what do i do to fix it?

Comment: before $new_album variable, add mysql_set_charset('utf8',$database);